# Uninstall XCode CLI tools

Tags: xcode, macos, xcode5

I’ve installed the latest Xcode CLI tools (the ones you can [get directly](http://developer.apple.com/downloads), without having to install XCode).

I’d now like to uninstall them completely, how would one go about doing that?

Comment: Following the link (even though the solution does not work in Mavericks), it seems it may be a case of removing '/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools' '/var/db/receipts/com.apple.pkg.CLTools_Executables.bom' '/var/db/receipts/com.apple.pkg.CLTools_Executables.plist', and maybe some other files/dirs.

Answer (score -1):

I *beleive* that they actually live inside the Xcode.app executable. 
If you ctrl-click / right-click on the app and select Show Package Contents then you'll see the file structure inside.

Look in Contents > Developer > usr and you'll see the command line utilities.
What I'm not certain about is how links to such tools as git and svn might be changed as part of the install process. But this should certainly get you going for now.

As a result simply deleting either the whole Xcode app or selected items ion the bundle will do what you want.

To ask the question behind the the question, is there anything specific you want to remove or change?

Comment: Like I said, I’ve installed them directly, **without** Xcode, so I cannot do that.

Comment: My bad! Sorry. OK, thinking.... have you looked in /Library/Receipts, /System/Library/Receipts and ~/Library/Receipts to see if there's a text file or .bom file with information on where they were installed? Next try Console.app and hunt for log files of installs. The first one to try is /var/log/install.log